# Can ampscript determine if a DE exists or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Does anyone know a way to determine with ampscript whether a DE exists or not prior to doing a LookupRows()? In my case, the DE I'm looking up may or may not exist. And if it doesn't, I wanted to stop the send for that subscriber and not the entire job. My current code is below. Tips and tricks are much appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone.

```
%%[
IF DataExtensionRowCount("THIS_DE_DOES_NOT_EXIST") > 0 THEN
 SET @TEST = "Good Test, your DE exists do your lookup here"
ELSE
 RaiseError("Bad Test, your DE does not exist", true)
ENDIF
]%%
<strong>%%=v(@TEST)=%%</strong>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my test, one of the ways you can achieve this is by using SSJS. You will setup your SSJS within an email. If you use the `try` and `catch` functions within SSJS and wrap your lookup functions then you can manipulate the errors.

Here is an example:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    try {
        var CheckDE = DataExtension.Init("DE_Name_TO_Check");
        var CheckDEStatus = CheckDE.Rows.Lookup(["FieldName"],[Value]);
    }
    catch (e) {
        Platform.Function.RaiseError("DE does not exist",true,"statusCode","3");
    }
</script>
```

Breakdown:

The `try` block is running the lookup rows function and checking to see if the rows exists in a specific DE. Since DE doesn't exists the function will error and it will return you to the `catch` block where you can set your SSJS [RaiseError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityRaiseError.htm) function.

Also the true status in the RaiserError function will only stop the send for a specific subscriber and proceed to next subscriber send.

Comment: Hi @Brad Sapkota, I like the direction but when I paste your code into my email it gives me an error that says "An error occurred when attempting to execute a Javascript block. See inner exception for detail." rather than it initiating the RaiseError. Any thoughts there?

Comment: Are you using classic content builder or modern content builder?

Comment: Hi Brad, I built this in classic. It's a standard html/paste email.

Comment: @Nolan The script works perfectly fine, I have test it myself. Just to give you a context, the system shows you error while doing a send preview because this is what RaiseError is doing in back-end. If you try doing a guided send with a script the email send doesn't fail but stops from sending email to the subscribers which is kind of a real way to test this case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Brad, ahh that makes perfect sense. I'll give that a shot and see how it goes. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated.