# Only execute Data Extension AMPscript functions if the Data Extension exists

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I had a client ask me last week how you can put a conditional statement around a Data Extension function, where if the Data Extension does not exist, then don't process the code within it. The AMPscript is used in an email.

There are many scenarios why you would want to do this. For example, perhaps the Data Extension has been deleted due to an assigned Data Retention Policy.

The following code...

```js
%%[
var @rows
set @rows = LookupRows('DE Name', 'Field', 'Value')
]%%
```

...returns the error:

> The Data Extension name for a LookupRows function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist

You can't try counting the rows either. For example, the following code also returns the same error.

```js
%%[
if RowCount(LookupRows('DE Name', 'Field', 'Value')) == 0 then
/* do something */
endif
]%%
```

I thought that perhaps you could first use WSProxy or platform API functions to try and retrieve the External Key of the DE name, and if it returns a value, then you could set the DE name as a variable in an AMPscript DE function, but this isn't possible as you can't use WSProxy or platform API functions in a send context.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/can-ampscript-determine-if-a-de-exists-or-not/210117#210117

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the approach is similar to a previous [**post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/can-ampscript-determine-if-a-de-exists-or-not/210117#210117), I have reused the same code and made some slight modifications.

I have used the mixture of SSJS and AMPscript to cover this use case for the LookUp Rows.

The script below uses `try` and `catch` within SSJS to execute AMPscript and `SET` a variable which then can be used later in your email to run logic based on the value of that resulted variable.

If you copy and run this straight within an email the result will be **`false`** assuming this DE doesn't exist in your BU. However, if you change it to valid DE Name and a valid field in SSJS and render the email the result will be **`true`**.

Example:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    try {
        var CheckDE = DataExtension.Init("DE_Name_TO_Check");
        var CheckDEStatus = CheckDE.Rows.Lookup(["FieldName"], [Value]);
</script>

    %%[SET @DEExists = "true"]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
    }
    catch (e) {
</script>

    %%[SET @DEExists = "false"]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript">
Platform.Load("core", "1");
    }
</script>

This is to confirm if DE Exists: %%=v(@DEExists)=%%
```

Comment: You could also set the `@DEExists` variable with SSJS to keep the logic within one language like `Variable.SetValue("@DEExists", "true");`

Comment: While this verifies if the DE exists, it does not solve the issue. As per the second code example in my question, I still want to perform a LookupRows operation if `@DEExists == true`, but the LookupRows function is still evaluated, even though it's wrapped in a conditional statement, as per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/329165f6d8489ebf72d39fcfe88fd184).

Comment: The LookUpRows is already performed in the try step, so basically why would you do a LookUpRows twice? or if you do need to perform LookUpRows again, can you not do it within the try block where the AMPscript is set? Since that part of the AMPScript will only execute if the DE and fields are valid.

Comment: You're right. I've been looking at this for too long.

Comment: fair enough. Thank you for accepting the solution. cheers

Comment: @TravisNaughton sure makes sense. However, I thought OP might want to run more logics using AMPscript within the try and catch block :)

Comment: @BradSapkota - To speed this up, you don't need to declare the CORE library or Initiate the DE, you can use `Platform.Function.LookupRows('DE_Name_To_Check','FieldName',value');` which does not require CORE. It will only be a slight improvement in processing speed, but every millisecond counts inside email processing. Other than that, great job finding a simple solution for a complex issue!

Comment: no worries @Gortonington will remember this and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I would use @BradSapkota's answer (utilizing SSJS try/catch) for this issue, but wanted to leave this here for reference in case this answer can help another related use case.

---

I would recommend doing this via WSProxy - but even so, it can run a bit slow and should never be used in a sendable environment.

As you need it inside an email, your only real choice would be to have this code on a CloudPage and then do an HTTPGET to this page and send across the DE as a parameter in the get. You can then have the page return a value of "Exists" or "Empty" via the GET that you can then parse.

**CloudPage**

You can do a filtered retrieve request and then do a rowcount on the reponse to see if it returned empty or if it returns the DE info.

For Example:

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["Name"];
var filter = {
    Property: "Name",
    SimpleOperator: "equals",
    Value: "yourDE"
};
var desc = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter);
```

Example Empty Response:

```
{
  "Status":"OK",
  "RequestID":"d1db75de-5736-4634-ab71-297e7e7d1571",
  "Results":[],
  "HasMoreRows":false
}
```

Example Existing Response:

```
{
  "Status":"OK",
  "RequestID":"d333fcc9-8b0d-4799-ace6-50340fbe482d",
  "Results":[{"Name":"yourDE"}],
  "HasMoreRows":false
}
```

and from there you parse the "Results" array to see if it contains the data extension in question's info. If it does not, then you know it does not exist.

For example:

```
 if(desc.Results.length > 0) {

     Write('Exists');

} else {

    Write('Empty')

}
```

**Inside Email**

You would place the following GET script inside the email to return the results from the CP.

```
%%[
    SET @deExist = HTTPGet(@yourURL)

    IF @deExist == "Exists" THEN

      /* Your stuff if it exists*/

    ELSE

      /* Your stuff if empty */

    ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I need to this in an email. As per my last paragraph in my question, I considered this approach too, but you can’t use WSProxy in an email :-/

Comment: You are right, you did - I apologize! That is what I get for skimming it :( I edited my question to reflect usage inside of an email.

Comment: My only hesitation now in accepting this answer in it's current form is that this will make one request for each email (and others may hit this issue if they try this answered question). If you are sending thousands of emails, this could be problematic. It would be ideal if we could use [Content Syndication](https://ampscript.guide/book/beforehttpget/) to make the request once, as the start of the send (assuming that the Data Extension name won't change, and in this scenario, let's say it won't). However I haven't been able to get `Before;HTTPGet` to work inside of an AMPscript block.

Comment: If you can come up with a solution, I'd be happy to accept this, but I don't feel comfortable about accepting it in its current form as I wouldn't want others to implement it and hit rate limiting issues on CloudPages (which I've seen before).

Comment: Spitballing - what if you create a de with the job number as the pkey, and a field next to it with de status then have the page insert into that de. In email you can have an if statement to run httpget if lookup on that de based on job number comes back empty else use the DE value returned

Comment: And in case of multiple DEs, you could store jobID and DE name as pkeys to allow more then one to be used per job

Comment: I think Brad has the answer for this one using try/catch as per his comment on my question, which would be a better approach then HTTPGet on a CP. Let me know your thoughts and I will close as duplicate (which is what it is). +1 anyway for your help.

Comment: Can I post my answer and would that be an acceptable solution to you? @EliotHarper

Comment: @BradSapkota while you have already answered that question and we want to avoid duplicates on SFSE, the context of the previous question was different (he wanted to skip sending the email), so I think it's appropriate to add a new answer. That is, if you provide an example that only performs a LookupRows operation if the DE exists.

Comment: Agreed. It's amazing how the simple solutions always seem the hardest to come by. Good work brad

Comment: thank you @Gortonington. The try and catch is underrated and can be used in so many different scenarios.